# Is there way of copying the whole array into another array? (Other than using a For-loop)

Tags: delphi

Is there way of copying the whole array into another array? Other than using a for-loop.

Does the [move](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Move) or [copy](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Copy) command work for this? 
I did try but it had an error: "Incompatible types".

Should I stick to the for-loop?

Comment: Move uses a for loop. At least it did in Delphi 7. What code caused the error?

Comment: I didn't know that. Move and Copy both caused an error. (I didn't use them at the same time though)

Comment: Move doesn't uses a for loop. It's written in asm, even in Delphi 7, and use either a rep movsd/movsb with Delphi 7, or much faster FPU instructions in newer Delphi version.

Comment: If the arrays are of the same type and fixed (not dynamic) size then you can copy by simply assigning one to the other (array1 := array2).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is a dynamic array. But I'll file that away for future reference. thanks. :D

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. It is appreciated (and upvoted). :D

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To be on the safe side, use the `Copy` function on dynamic arrays, as it handles the managed types internally. The arrays must be of the same type, i.e. declared in the same expression:

```
var  
    a, b: array of string;
```

or by defining a custom array type:

```
type   
    TStringArray = array of string;  
var 
    a: TStringArray;  
//...and somewhere else
var  
    b: TStringArray;
```

then you can do:

```
a := Copy(b, Low(b), Length(b));  //really clean, but unnecessary 
//...or   
a := Copy(b, 0, MaxInt);  //dynamic arrays always have zero low bound 
                          //and Copy copies only "up to" Count items
```

You'll have to use a loop on static arrays and when mixing array types (not that I'd recommend doing it).
If you really have to use `Move`, remember checking for zero-length, as the `A[0]` constructs can raise range checking errors, (with the notable exception of `SizeOf(A[0])`, which is handled by compiler magic and never actually executes).
Also *never* assume that `A = A[0]` or `SizeOf(A) = Length(A) * SizeOf(A[0])`, as this is true only for static arrays and it will bite you really badly if you later try to refactor huge codebase to dynamic arrays.

Comment: Although it's convenient to use hard-coded upper and lower bounds like 0 and `MaxInt`, it's even more convenient to omit the bounds entirely: `a := Copy(b)`. That copies the entire array.

Comment: @Viktor, you might share the `Copy(Source)` trick with our Czech *"MVP"*, as it seems he just discovered the possibility of omitting the last parameter (shame on me to accidentally visiting their blog).

Answer (score 6):

See [article on delphibasics.co.uk](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Copy)

You can copy an array using Copy method (pass in 0 for the index and Length(Source) as count to copy the full contents).

Do NOT use Move or CopyMemory for arrays of string/array/interface/etc managed types. Doing so will bypass Delphi's ref-counting mechanics and will result in memory leaks and corrupted data.

Comment: I think this small/simple answer is the best/most efficient answer.

Answer (score 6):

For dynamic arrays:

```
var A,B: array of Byte;

begin
  SetLength(A, <size>);
  //initialize A

  B:= A; 
  SetLength(B,Length(A));
end;
```

In dynamic arrays, the assignment statement duplicates only the reference to the array, while SetLength does the job of physically copying/duplicating it, leaving two separate, independent dynamic arrays.

Comment: Why not directly use:     a := Copy(b, 0, MaxInt); ?

Answer (score 3):

1- If your array doesn't contain any string or dynamic array, you can use move, but dynamic arrays are not to be handled like fixed-sized arrays:

```
var A,B: array[0..10] of integer;
    DA, DB: array of double;
    i: integer;
begin
  for i := low(A) to high(A) do
    A[i] := i;
  move(A[0],B[0],length(A)*sizeof(A[0]));  // first version, compiler does the stuff
  move(A[0],B[0],sizeof(A)); // it works
  move(A[0],B[0],40); // if you know what you're doing, since sizeof(A)=40
  SetLength(DA,10); // DA[0]..DA[9]
  for i := 0 to high(DA) do // or for i := 0 to 9 if you know what you're doing
    DA[i] := 
  SetLength(DB,length(DA)); 
  if length(DA)<=length(DB) then // if your dynamic array may be void, use this before to avoid GPF
    move(DA[0],DB[0],length(DA)*sizeof(DA[0]));
  if pointer(DA)<>nil then // this will just check that DA[] is not void
    move(pointer(DA)^,pointer(DB)^,length(DA)*sizeof(double)); // similar to previous
end;
```

2- If your array contains strings or other reference content array, you have to use a loop:

```
var A,B: array[0..10] of string;
    i: integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to high(A) do
    A[i] := IntToStr(i);
  for i := 0 to high(A) do
    B[i] := A[i]; // this doesn't copy the string content, just add a reference count to every A[], and copy a pointer: it's very fast indeed.
end;
```

Comment: "if you know what you're doing, since sizeof(A)=40"
It's 44.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a record type that uses a generic function to copy arrays to a dynamic TArray variable, which I have started using:

```
 TGen = record // Unused record to allow generic functions.
 public
      ...
       class function arrayCopy<T>(const a: array of T): TArray<T>; static;
 end;



class function TGen.arrayCopy<T>(const a: array of T): TArray<T>;
var i: integer;
begin
  SetLength(result, length(a));
  for i := Low(a) to High(a) do
    result[i] := a[i];
end;
```

Given a form variable

```
dtls: TArray<TGridSetupDetails>;
```

and a parameter assigned from an array over an enumerated type

```
const adtls: array of TGridSetupDetails
```

you can initialize the form variable:

```
  dtls := TGen.arrayCopy<TGridSetupDetails>(adtls);
```

Comment: This will be super slow for large arrays!

Comment: Gabriel: Yes, it is not optimized, but so far it has served me well, because in general I find my arrays are fairly short. It is at least clear; there are no hidden behaviours.

Comment: Also, given the function signature TGen.arrayCopy<T>(const a: array of T): TArray<T>, the code result := copy(a, 0, length(a)); doesn't compile. If I change the parameter to const a: TArray<T>, it does not accept static arrays.