# Delphi 2006 - Assigning dynamic array function results

Tags: delphi, variable-assignment, dynamic-arrays, delphi-2006

I had code with the basic constructs illustrated by the following:

```
type
    TDynamicArray = array of double ;

var
    a : TDynamicArray ;

    function Func : TDynamicArray ;

    var
        b : TDynamicArray ;

    begin
    SetLength (B, 3) ;
    b [0] := 0.0 ;
    b [1] := 1.0 ;
    b [2] := 2.0 ;
    Result := b ;   // note 1  -- should use Result := Copy (b, 0, Length (b)) 
    end ;

begin
a := Func ;  // note 2  -- should we (or could we) use a := Copy (Func, 0, Length (Func)) 
end.
```

It had been working fine until lately when the function started returning empty arrays.  I then spot [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3545449/is-there-way-of-copying-the-whole-array-into-another-array-other-than-using-a) which enlightens me to the fact that simple assignment isn't correct, I need to use `Copy`.

Two questions:

- I realise I need 'Copy' on the line marked `Note 1` to assign to the
  function result.  Do I need to use `Copy` also on the assignment of
  the function result to array `a` (line `Note 2`)?.
- Why did the compiler allow my construct and what was the compiled code actually
  doing?

I realise I could try these things and see, but I'm a little spooked by the compiler letting questionable stuff through.

Comment: As an aside, you certainly wouldn't want the `Copy (Func, ...` as you show in your comment since it would run `Func` twice. But to your ain issue, I'm not sure how Delphi handles a local dynamic array variable. I would go with the copy to `result` in the function, or just use `result` directly.

Comment: There's no problem with that code, the array is still heap allocated and ref counted. You might as well work directly on the 'result'.

Comment: @Sertac aaahhh... which code?  The real code can't really be structured to work directly on the function result.  I need to be able to assign a local array to `Result`.

Comment: @ross - That's fine. Still, what's on the stack is a pointer to the array - the array itself is on the heap. As long as you keep a reference to the array it won't get finalized. The link you refer to does not seem to be related.

Comment: If you really think you need to copy an array — which isn't as often as you think it is, I promise — note that you don't need to know its length. You can call `Copy` with just one argument and it will copy the entire array, no matter its length. The documentation even says so.

Comment: Your code works although it is needlessly complex. You really ought to post code that illustrates the phenomenon you describe. We can't tell you why your code returns empty arrays. This code **never** does. Copy won't help you. It just slows you down. You need an accurate problem diagnosis.

Comment: OK @sertac, @david, I might have been a bit hasty in deciding there was something amiss with the way I was doing things.  For whatever reason, I was getting unexpected results, and when I found the other posting, it contained the comment: `If the arrays are of the same type and fixed (not dynamic) size then you can copy by simply assigning one to the other (array1 := array2)` - implication being that if they _are_ dynamic, you _cant_ do that.  I will stick with the simple assignment and look for other reasons as to why it isn't reliable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason to use `Copy` in either of those assignment statements. Normal assignment works fine. When you allocate `b`, the reference count of the array is 1. When you assign it to `Result`, the reference count becomes 2. (Personally, I'd just forego `b` and operate directly on `Result` from the start.) When the function returns, `b` goes out of scope and the reference count becomes 1 again. Finally, when the result is assigned to `a`, nothing happens because `Result` was actually an alias for `a` all along. Ultimately, you're left with one unique array, which should be exactly what you intended.

The compiler allowed your code because your code is fine. The compiler recognizes assignments between arrays just as it does assignments between strings and assignments between interface references, and it generates the right code to adjust the reference counts accordingly.

Using `Copy` would create an entire copy of the array, but you don't need that. Each time you think you need it, it's in a place where you would have immediately discarded the previous copy anyway. Why make a copy when you already have a perfectly good array ready for any use you want?