# why the value of the F_pBest is changed after updating X?

Tags: delphi, debugging

In this Delphi code, why the value of **F_pBest** is changed after updating **X**?

It should be same value before updating **X**

Delphi Code:

```
        ...........

type TMDarray = array of array of Double;

       ............

  public
    { Public declarations }
     X, pBest : TMDarray;
     F_X, F_pBest : array of Double;
     D, maxIter, N : Integer;
     Lower, Upper : Double;   
  end;
 .................
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin
       main();
  end;

function TForm1.FitnessFunc(X : array of Double): Double;
var
  sum : Double;
  i, j : Integer;
begin
    d := length(X);
    sum := 0;
    for j := 1 to D-1 do
        sum := sum + x[j] * x[j];

    Result := sum;
end;

procedure  TForm1.initialize();
var
  i, j : Integer;
begin
      Lower := 0.0;
      Upper := 10.0;
      D := 3;
      N := 6;
      maxiter := 1;
      SetLength(X, N, D);
      SetLength(pBest, N, D);
      SetLength(F_X, N);
      SetLength(F_pBest, N);
     for  i:= 0 to N-1 do
      begin
             for j:=0 to D-1 do
           begin
                 X[i][j]:= Lower + (Upper - Lower) * Random;
           end;

          F_X[i] := FitnessFunc(X[i]);
      end;
      pBest := X;
      F_pBest := F_X;
end;
```

The main function:

```
procedure TForm1.main();
var
  iter, j, i : Integer;

  begin
      initialize();
        iter := 0;
      while (iter < maxiter) do
       begin
```

//======================= before update X ===========

```
             for  i:= 0 to N-1 do
             begin
               StringGrid3.Cells[0,i] := FloatToStr( F_X[i] );
               StringGrid3.Cells[1,i] := FloatToStr( F_pBest[i] );
             end;

      //===========================================================
             for  i:= 0 to N-1 do
              begin
                   for j:= 0 to D-1 do
                    begin
                        X[i][j] := Random();
                    end;
              end;

              for  i := 0 to N-1 do
               begin
                   F_X[i] := FitnessFunc(X[i]); // Update X
```

//======================= AFTER update X ===========

```
                  StringGrid3.Cells[2,i] := FloatToStr( F_X[i] );
                  StringGrid3.Cells[3,i] := FloatToStr( F_pBest[i] );
              end;
   //=======================================
              iter := iter + 1;
           end;
 end;
end.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your initialization, you run this: `F_pBest := F_X`. That *discards* the array previously referenced by `F_pBest` (as set when you called `SetLength` on it) and instead makes `F_pBest` be an *alias* for `F_X`. Changes to the array through one variable are reflected through any other variables that reference the same array.

Dynamic arrays are reference counted like strings, but unlike strings, they are not implicitly copied when modified by index.

Techniques for [creating an independent copy of a dynamic array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3545449/33732) have been discussed here before.