# Recommended way to copy an open array

Tags: delphi

Other than using a for loop, what is the recommended way of copying the contents on one open array to another open array as quickly as possible? In this case the array is a simple array of doubles, you can assume that the source and target arrays have the same size.

```
myValues : array of double;
```

I saw an answer to this question [How to copy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1119215/how-to-copy-array) which uses Move. Is this a reasonable approach to take or are there alternatives? Such copying will be done frequently so I am looking for the most efficient way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you ask about copying from one open array to another, I wonder if that's what you actually want to do. I suspect that you are actually using terminology rather loosely. The question that you link to covers copying an open array to a dynamic array. I assume that's what you really want to do.

If you know that the base type is unmanaged, and that a raw memory copy is valid, then you will struggle to beat the performance of `Move`. But only contemplate `Move` if performance of that part of your code is critical. Using untyped operations is best avoided unless there are compelling reasons to abandon the security of the type system.

For a general purpose array copy, I use this type:

```
type
  TArray = class(Generics.Collections.TArray)
  public
    class function Copy<T>(const Source: array of T; Index, Count: Integer): TArray<T>; overload; static;
    class function Copy<T>(const Source: array of T): TArray<T>; overload; static;
  end;

class function TArray.Copy<T>(const Source: array of T; Index, Count: Integer): TArray<T>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Count);
  for i := 0 to high(Result) do begin
    Result[i] := Source[i+Index];
  end;
end;

class function TArray.Copy<T>(const Source: array of T): TArray<T>;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(Source));
  for i := 0 to high(Result) do begin
    Result[i] := Source[i];
  end;
end;
```

The type has lots and lots of other methods that I have omitted for brevity.

Comment: Funny you should ask. After I posted the question, I thought, I know what's going to happen, they are going to ask 'Why do I need to copy the array?' So I thought about the problem a bit more and realized I didn't need to copy the arrays after all. I think however the question is still work asking because there will be other cases where  copying arrays is a legitimate operation. Hence I feel the answers given will be useful to others even if the question is somewhat now redundant to me at the moment.

Comment: Ok. Obviously doing nothing is always faster!

Comment: @rhody, if you define your `array of double` as a type and for that type you write a method for copying, then it would be type safe and (most) efficient if you use `Move` there.